# How to determine if scraped HTML element has a class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the timetable from this website [Medmar](https://www.medmargroup.it/) and would like to determine the **li** items that have the class **.tratta**, so that I can build a JSON with this format where ROUTE is the text I get from the **li** item with class **.tratta** and departure time from the others

```
{'ROUTE': 'Casamicciola >> Pozzuoli', 'DEPARTURE TIME': '08:00'}
```

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

medmar_live_departures_url = "https://www.medmargroup.it/"
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.3'}
request = urllib.request.Request(medmar_live_departures_url,headers=headers)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
medmar_live_departures_data = []
medmar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('.primarystyle-timetable li'))
for li in medmar_live_departures_table:
    if  li.get("class") == "tratta" :
        medmar_live_departures_data.append(
        {
        'ROUTE': li.text
        })
    else:
        medmar_live_departures_data.append(
        {
        'DEPARTURE TIME': li.select('strong').text
        })
```

**EDIT**
My code currently returns this error:

```
 'DEPARTURE TIME': li.select('strong').text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt? Errors?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add. See edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first problem, `li.select('strong')` should be `li.select_one('strong')` or just `li.strong.text` to return first element.

second problem, `.get("class")` will return array like `["tratta"]`

```
if  li.get("class") == "tratta" : # not correct
if  li.get("class") == ["tratta"] : # correct
if  "tratta" in li.get("class") : # correct
```

third problem, your dict result is not valid

```
[
  {'ROUTE': 'NAPOLI PORTA DI MASSA » ISCHIA'}, 
  {'DEPARTURE TIME': '08:35'},
  {'DEPARTURE TIME': '14:10'},
  {'ROUTE': 'POZZUOLI » ISCHIA'},
  {'DEPARTURE TIME': '06:10'},
  {'DEPARTURE TIME': '09:40'}, ....
]
```

The correct logic is `DEPARTURE TIME` is a `list`

```
[
  {'ROUTE': 'NAPOLI PORTA DI MASSA » ISCHIA', 'DEPARTURE TIME': ['08:35', '14:10', '18:30']},
  {'ROUTE': 'POZZUOLI » ISCHIA', 'DEPARTURE TIME': ['06:10', '09:40', '13:30', '16:30', '20:30']}
]
```

and here are working code

```
medmar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('li.tratta'))

DEPARTURE_TIME = []
for li in medmar_live_departures_table:
    next_li = li.find_next_sibling("li")
    while next_li and next_li.get("data-toggle"):
        DEPARTURE_TIME.append(next_li.strong.text)
        next_li = next_li.find_next_sibling("li")
    medmar_live_departures_data.append({
          'ROUTE' : li.text,
          'DEPARTURE TIME' : DEPARTURE_TIME
    })
    DEPARTURE_TIME = []

print(medmar_live_departures_data)
```

I use selector `li.tratta` for `ROUTE` value and find_next_sibling() to search for attribute `data-toggle` that will be values for `DEPARTURE TIME`

Comment: Thank you for you help. Great answer.

Comment: I've tried to amend you code to determine if a next_li has class .corsa-yes, so I can add to the JSON list  'STATUS': "active". I've tried the following right after the while statement:   if "corsa-yes" in next_li.get("class"):
            medmar_live_departures_data.append({
                   'STATUS': "active" 
            }). I've tried the following